# Facebook deleted all my applications because of someone tried to access my Facebook account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

Yesterday I got a message from Facebook inform that someone tried to access my Facebook account! Well, it's not a problem because I'm securing it.

The problem is related to my applications, more than 4 apps has been disappeared without any details from Facebook!
When I try to make a brand new app, I get a message that about I couldn't create a new application because this activity is temporary blocked to in my Facebook account!

My Facebook developer account is already verified by phone. Was running a lot of apps since 2014.

Please any Facebook developers here to help me?

Comment: Go to https://developers.facebook.com/appeal and appeal

Comment: Man you helped me a lot.. thank you :)

Comment: Please, could I get some details around why all those apps moved to appeal page!

Comment: The page doesn't say? And the email didn't say?

Comment: The say that there's two reasons: Facebook automatically flagged all the apps as spam apps or that was by a mistake from Facebook.

Comment: I have just received one email from Facebook inform that some tried to access to my FB account!